# Laravel scout + tntsearch is returning empty collection while searching with uuid

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-scout

I'm using laravel scout with tntsearch driver in a laravel 7 project. Scout is always returning an empty collection if I search by id(uuid). But I get search results as expected if I search with fields other than id.

### Controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $coverNotes = null;

    if (request('search'))
    {
        $coverNotes = CoverNote::search(request('search'))->paginate(1); // it is always empty while searching with id, which is of 'uuid' type
    }
    else
    {
        $coverNotes = $this->coverNote->paginate(1);
    }

    return View::make('cover-notes.index', compact('coverNotes'));
}
```

### Model

```
class CoverNote extends Model
{
    use Searchable, UuidTrait;

    public $asYouType = false;

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $array = $this->toArray();

        return $array;
    }

}
```

### config/scout.php

```
'queue' => env('SCOUT_QUEUE', false),  // I didn't set it on .env

'tntsearch' => [
    'storage'  => storage_path(), //place where the index files will be stored
    'fuzziness' => env('TNTSEARCH_FUZZINESS', false),
    'fuzzy' => [
        'prefix_length' => 2,
        'max_expansions' => 50,
        'distance' => 2
    ],
    'asYouType' => false,
    'searchBoolean' => env('TNTSEARCH_BOOLEAN', false),
],
```

### scout:status

```
 ---------------------- ------------------- ----------------- --------------- ------------ -------------------- 
  Searchable             Index               Indexed Columns   Index Records   DB Records   Records difference  
 ---------------------- ------------------- ----------------- --------------- ------------ -------------------- 
  App\Models\CoverNote   cover_notes.index                     1               1            Synchronized        
 ---------------------- ------------------- ----------------- --------------- ------------ --------------------
```